# Get daily news feed from Wikinews

Tags: python, web-scraping

want to get the title of news every 4 hours from news feed and store it in DB.

Code I tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
import random
import re

url="https://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Main_Page"
reqs = requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
for title in soup.find(id='MainPage_latest_news_text').findAll('title'):
    print(title.get_text())
```

I successfully get the newsfeed from google and store it but want to do the same for the Wikinews.

```
googlenews = GoogleNews(start=Start_date,end=End_date)
googlenews.set_lang('en')
googlenews.set_encode('utf-8')
googlenews.get_news('Business')
googlenews.total_count()
result=googlenews.result()
df=pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can do it by using selenium.**

from selenium import webdriver

*##path to your chrome driver##*

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="drivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Main_Page")

results=[]

for i in range(1,4):

***##this code is under for loop indent##***

heading=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td["+str(i)+"]/table/tbody/tr/td/span/a").text

results.append(heading)

***##outsidee for loop indent ##***

print(results)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer to the question. It's helpful to take a little time to format your post to make it easier to read.